# What are the different monsters featured in The Witcher?

Tags: the-witcher

There are a number of non-human creatures featured in The Witcher tv series. Some of these are very different from how they have been previously depicted/described in the lore and some have not been mentioned in previous works at all.

What are all the creatures featured? And what are their folkloric inspirations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Featured

- [**Djinn**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinn)
- [**Dryad**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dryad)
- [**Basilisk**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basilisk)
- **Hirikka** (?)
- **Striga** ([shtriga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shtriga))
- **Witcher** ([vedmak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedmak))
- **Doppler** ([doppelgänger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppelg%C3%A4nger))
- **Cursed Knight** ([Hans-my-Hedgehog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_My_Hedgehog))
  <sup>Urcheon = old word for hedgehog</sup>
- [**Kikimora**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kikimora)
  <sup>Show appearance very different from folklore descriptions.</sup>
- **Sylvan** ([Silvanus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silvanus_(mythology)), [faun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faun))
  <sup>Name also used to describe forest elves in *The Lord of the Rings*, and tree spirits in *The Chronicles of Narnia*.</sup>
- [**Dragon**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_dragon)

  - Green, Red, Black Dragon ([D&D Chromatic Dragons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)#Chromatic_dragons))
  - Golden Dragon ([zmeu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zmeu), [zmey](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavic_dragon), [D&D Golden Dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)#Metallic_dragons))

#### Mentioned

- [**Manticore**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manticore)
- **Lilit** ([Lilith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilith))
- **Graveir** ([goul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghoul))
- **Selkiemore** ([selkie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selkie), [leviathan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leviathan))
- [**Vukodlak**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vrykolakas#Etymology)
  <sup>Stylised [brukołak](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Brukolak) in the games. Various similar spellings in different languages.</sup>

Comment: Ghouls feature in episode 7.

Comment: Which one of these is the creature commanded by the assassin in episode 4? I guessed it was an Endrega.

Comment: Would the dryads of Brokiloén forest be considered non-human?